# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de getch(); en Perl?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, perl

Estoy programando un menú de opciones en Perl, pero necesito una función equivalente al `getch()` de C++ en Perl, para poder mostrar la salida, y el `sleep 1;` no funciona a como quiero. Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
while ($input ne '6') {
    clear_screen();
    print "\n\n\t\t\t\tFunciones Sobre Cadenas de Caracteres\n\n";
    print "1. opcion 1\n".
          "2. opcion 2\n". 
          "3. opcion 3\n". 
          "4. opcion 4\n". 
          "5. opcion 5\n".
          "6. salir\n";

    print "Introduce tu opcion: ";
    $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp($input);
    sleep 1;  #aquí necesito la función equivalente a getch()
    
    switch ($input)
    {
        case '2'
        {
            $input = '';
        
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función en Perl se llama `getc`. Tienes su documentación, en tu ordenador, ejecutando el comando

```
perldoc -f getc
```

Ejemplo: http://perlenespanol.com/foro/post34771.html#p34771

Otra forma es leyendo la entrada estándar, esperando por un solo carácter. Así:

```perl
    sysread( STDIN, $búfer, 1 );
```

El programa se detendrá en esa línea a la llegada de un carácter. Pero esto no es tan simple: depende de la consola y sistema operativo que estés usando. Echa un vistazo al código fuente del módulo Term::Screen, donde implementa una función getch() completa:
https://metacpan.org/release/Term-Screen/source/lib/Term/Screen.pm#L474

Otro detalle: al hacerlo así no podrás, fácilmente, tener más de 10 opciones (necesitas pulsar dos veces). Otros módulos, como Term::Menus, son más recomendables para hacer menús.